# Trouble finding homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have the following congruence subgroups:
$$\begin{align}
\Gamma_1(N)&=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\
c&d \end{bmatrix} \in \operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}): \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\
c&d \end{bmatrix} \equiv\begin{bmatrix} 1 & * \\
0&1 \end{bmatrix}\pmod{N}\right\}
\\
\Gamma_0(N)&=\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\
c&d \end{bmatrix} \in \operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}): \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\
c&d \end{bmatrix} \equiv\begin{bmatrix} * & * \\
0&* \end{bmatrix}\pmod{N}\right\}
\end{align}$$

I want to show that $\Gamma_1(N)$ is a normal subgroup of $\Gamma_0(N)$ so I want to find a homomorphism from $\Gamma_0(N)$ to some group and show that the kernel of this homomorphism is $\Gamma_1(N)$. But I don't seem to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group is the multiplicative group of diagonal matrices mod $N.$

Answer (score 1):

**Exercise:** Verify that the following
$$\phi\colon\ \Gamma_0(N)\mapsto(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})^\times,\quad
\phi\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix} = d$$
is a group homomorphism with kernel $\Gamma_1(N)$.

**Exercise:** Show that replacing the above right-hand side with $a$
works as well.

**Bonus exercise:** Verify that
$$\psi\colon\ \Gamma_1(N)\mapsto\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z},\quad
\psi\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{pmatrix} = b$$
is a group homomorphism and find its kernel.
Note that the right-hand side's group operation is addition this time.